# Get random NSDictionary Key?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary

Hello StackOverflow Community,

```
<plist>
<dict>
    <key>Non Random Key</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Random Key</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hello</key>
            <string>Hey</string>
            <key>Banana</key>
            <string>Bread</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is my Plist File ... /this/is/the/path.plist

Now i want to get the "Hey" String from "Hello".

Solution for Non Random Key!
But i have a random Key, also this issn´t the Solution ...

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/this/is/the/path.plist"];

NSString *value;
value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"/Non Random Key/Random Key/Hello"];
// value is "Hey"
```

But how it works with this "Random Key"?

**Thank you in Advance.**

*And maybe, you can explain me, how i set a random key?
Also the Example at the Top but instead "Get" i would "Set" :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over the "Non Random Key" Dictionary. this should help: [NSDictionary iterate](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/iterating-through-nsdictionary.html)

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/this/is/the/path.plist"];

NSDictionary *nonRandomDic = [plistDic valueForKey:@"NonRandomKey"];


NSEnumerator *enumerator = [nonRandomDic keyEnumerator];
id key;
while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
  NSString *tmp = [nonRandomDic objectForKey:key];
  NSLog(@"Your String %@ from the Random Key %@", tmp, key);
}
```

Comment: you mean i should get the "Non Random Key" Plist into an extra Plist.
And then i make a "allKeys" Array with the new Plist.

Comment: Thank you meccan,
is this right, too????
Because i want to set it, too :)

http://pastebin.com/R6F02gPw

Or with your Example:
http://pastebin.com/nPjzG4TY

Comment: Why not use `[nonRandomDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Your String %@ from the Random Key %@", obj, key);
    }];`

Comment: @SkylarSch: Is this a Method of "RexEx" Searching Code? Like |\/NonRandomKey\/[0]\/Hello| or how the Script define "key", "obj" and "stop"? I mean, is not that a bit too easy? :D ---- And How i Set? With your Method?

Comment: @SkylarSch i love blocks but you should take attention for the Memory Management in the block e.g. __block vars. @ We Spire if the example do want you want, than you have the solution

Comment: Okay, Thank you Very Much @ meccan... And if i read the Article about "Memory Management" then i thank you SkylarSch, too! :)